# Simple Typescript Jasmine Test throwing 'expect' error

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following simple Jasmine test...

```
//test.spec.ts
describe('Sample', function(){
   it('Should do something', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

But when I run I get...

```
Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
```

This works just fine...

```
describe('Sample', function(){
   it('Should do something', function(){
      expect(true).toBe(true);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=describe('Sample'%2C%20function()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20it('Should%20do%20something'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20()%20%3D%3E%20expect(true).toBe(true))%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adescribe('Sample'%2C%20function()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20it('Should%20do%20something'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20expect(true).toBe(true))%3B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

If there are these two statements

```
describe('Sample', function(){
    it('Should do something',
        () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});

describe('Sample', function(){
    it('Should do something', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true));  
   } 
});
```

they result in different JS code

```
describe('Sample', function () {
    it('Should do something', function () { return expect(true).toBe(true); });
});
describe('Sample', function () {
    it('Should do something', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

A simple statement, without wrapping `{}` is transpiled into return statement, which we do not need here

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the reason you're getting it is the arrow function, which treats the scope differently then the regular anonymous functions.

When you're doing this:

```
it('Should do something', function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

The function is executed with spec as `this`, but when you use an arrow function:

```
it('Should do something', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

The `this` is different.

Easy to check, try:

```
it('Should do something', function() {
    console.log("this is: ", this);
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

And:

```
it('Should do something', () => {
    console.log("this is: ", this);
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```